# Jetpack Compose version

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I read about the compatibility among compose version and other dependencies:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility

But I seem not able to upgrade the compose version.  The following is what I have that is working:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_plugin_version = '8.1.4'
        kotlin_plugins_version = '1.7.21'
        nav_version = '2.5.3'
        hilt_version = '2.44.2'
        compose_version = '1.4.0-alpha02'
    }
}
```

If I change compose_version = '1.4.0', I will get gradle build error:
[image]

Execution failed for task ':app:compileProdDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

I must be missing something, anyone has any tips all appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This error you get because of **JetpackCompose `1.4.0` is compatible with Kotlin `1.8.0`**. In other words Compose `1.4.0` rely on some method that exists in Kotlin `1.8.0`, but this method is absent in Kotlin `1.7.21`.

Compatibility table is here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

[image: compose-1.4.0-compatibility]

So, the **solution for your case is to bump Kotlin to `1.8.0` version**.

---

Btw, if you want the most recent versions for today (2024-01-05), here they are:

```ini
androidGradlePlugin = "8.2.0"
kotlin = "1.9.21"  # check compose-compiler compatibility: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin
hilt = "2.48.1"
compose = "1.5.4"
composeCompilerExtension = "1.5.7"
```